# How to configure cloud foundry nginx_router to convert application with sub domain name as a path of the main application

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry

All

I am using CF v1, and we had several applications like:
 - abc.com 
 - admin.abc.com 
 - test.abc.com

Now, we have 3 DNS name for them and point to a same IP.
Is it possible that we only have one DNS name and convert the 2 sub domain as the path of the main application like
 - abc.com 
 - abc.com/admin 
 - abc.com/test

I tried to write something like 
    location =/admin {
      rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ ${scheme}://admin.${server_name}/$1 permanent;
    }
But then I found all the components cannot communicate with cloud controller.
I am some new here, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry does not support the ability to include the path component of a URI in the application route. However, this is a feature that many in the Cloud Foundry community would like to see added, and a Tracker item has been created [1] and added to the community backlog.

However, as CF,v1 has been deprecated for some time, now [2] even when the feature is added, it won't likely be back ported to v1.

[1] https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1151414/stories/92128632

[2] http://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/03/brief-history-cloud-foundry-and-stackato